# Python script to identify regex matches in all subdirs and write dict of matches to MongoDB

Tags: python, regex, mongodb

I've been attempting to teach myself Python over the past couple of months and have been setting myself practical challenges to learn different aspects of the language.

I have a deep structure of subdirectories containing `.rtf` files. The objectives of the following code are as follows:

1. Examine every file in every subdirectory to identify "flagged words" defined in `expression`.
2. For each instance a flagged word is identified in a file, capture the file name and the line within that file in which the flagged word appears.
3. Construct a dictionary, in which flagged words are keys and filenames and lines are stored as values.
4. Insert each key/value pair in the dictionary into a MongoDB collection

The code is as follows:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import os
import re
import json

# connect to mongodb

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['test-database']
restrictions = db['restrictions']

# create empty dictionary

d = {}

# setup regular expressions

expression = "sexual offences|reporting restriction|reporting restrictions|anonymous|anonymously|secret"
pattern = re.compile(expression)

# read the source files

for dname, dirs, files in os.walk("path/to/top/level/directory"):

    for fname in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(dname, fname)

        with open(fpath, 'r') as f:
            source = f.readlines()

            for i, line in enumerate(source):

                for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
                # set the matched flagword as the key and the filename and line as the value
                    d.setdefault(match.group(0), [])
                    file_instance = fname, line
                    print file_instance
                    d[match.group(0)].append(file_instance)


# Update the restrictions database

for key, value in d.iteritems():
    xref_id = db.restrictions.insert_one({'flagged_word': key, 'instance': value})
```

An example document in MongoDB generated by this code:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5925e0d94fb263cb1417bb73"),
        "flagged_word" : "restriction",
        "instance" : [ 
            [ 
                "Family3.txt ", 
                "ii)\tAn application for a reporting restriction order (\"reporting restriction order\") to restrict or prohibit the publication of:\n"
            ] 
    }
```

The code works as expected, but I have a nagging feeling that the same objectives could be achieved with a far less clunky approach in the code (particularly where all of the `for` loops are concerned).

In the spirit of wishing to learn how to write clearer, more Pythonic code, I wonder if anyone could offer some advice on how this code could be improved. Many thanks in advance for taking the time to read my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `f.readlines()` is redundant. Just iterate over the file: `for i, line in enumerate(f):`, or, as you are not using `i` at all: `for line in f:`
- `d.setdefault` becomes redundant if you use `d = collections.defaultdict(list)`